# input axis verticle is not set up in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
#pragma strict

var rb : Rigidbody;

function Start () {
    rb = GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
}

function FixedUpdate () {

    var moveHorizontal : float = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    var moveVertical : float = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    var movement : Vector3 = new Vector3(moveHorizontal,0.0,moveVertical); 
    rb.AddForce(movement);
}
```

It's my code in javascript for unity gaming engine. While taking input this error is showing.

**"input axis verticle is not set up in unity"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Input Manager window (you can find it under Edit->Project Settings->Input) and ensure that there is an axis with the name of "Vertical".